# Custom breadcrumb css stretch issue

Tags: css, html, breadcrumbs

I've created a custom breadcrumb in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jimbodeni/Ata9k/ . When you shrink the width of the page the text is on 2 lines on the last 2 breadcrumbs but is only on one line on the first breadcrumb. This causes the grey background to be out of line on the first breadcrumb with the other 2. 
How can I get this to always be the max height of the largest breadcrumb so they're all uniform height no matter if one has got one line of text and another 2 lines of text?

```
   <div id="breadcrumb-container">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="#">Surgery Started</a></li>    
            <li class="current"><a href="#">Surgery Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Surgery Compl'd</a></li>
        </ul>           
    </div>  


 div#breadcrumb-container {
width:100%;
}

div#breadcrumb-container li {
width: 33%;
}

div#breadcrumb-container li:last-child {
width: 34%;
}

.breadcrumb { 
list-style: none; 
overflow: hidden;     
font: 13px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;         
}
.breadcrumb li { 
float: left; 
background: #C7C7C7;

}
.breadcrumb li a {
color: white;
text-decoration: none; 
padding: 5px 5px 5px 45px;
position: relative; 
display: block;
}

.breadcrumb li a:after { 
content: " "; 
display: block; 
width: 0; 
height: 0;
border-top: 50px solid transparent;          
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
border-left: 30px solid #C7C7C7;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -50px; 
left: 100%;
z-index: 2; 
}

.breadcrumb li a:before { 
content: " "; 
display: block; 
width: 0; 
height: 0;
border-top: 50px solid transparent;       
border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
border-left: 30px solid #001940;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -50px; 
margin-left: 3px;  
left: 100%;
}

.breadcrumb li:first-child a {
padding-left: 12px;
border:none;
}

.breadcrumb li:last-child a:after {
border:none;    
}

.breadcrumb .current {
background:#007ACC; color:#fff;
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default; 
}

.breadcrumb .current a:after {
 border-left-color:#007ACC;
 pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
}

.breadcrumb li a:hover { background: #007ACC;  }
.breadcrumb li a:hover:after { border-left-color: #007ACC !important; }
```

Also, how do I get all 3 breadcrumbs to be exactly the same size? At the minute the first one is bigger than the other 2.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help!

Comment: Scary as it may seem, the most convenient answer lies in giving the `ul` a `display:table` and the `li` a `display:table-cell`. Given your specific situation I can't get it working entirely right though either.

Comment: Would you like it to be CSS only?

Comment: Doesn't have to be! Thanks for looking.

Comment: A bit more background on this - it's for an app I'm doing which will be compiled down to ios & android using PhoneGap (hence size being an issue). I've got 9 statuses which I only want to display 3 of these at anyone time. The last status, the present status and then next status. Clicking either the last status or next status will move the status back or forward and update the statuses accordingly. I was thinking a breadcrumb style was the way to go but it's becoming a pain!